# is there any way to delete pygame sprite image using a function?

Tags: python, pygame

As you can probabely tell by "self.image", it is meant to represent player's health. I wonder if there's any way to use "healthDeleted(self)" in order to remove(or change) self.image when a certain condition is met.

```
class Player_sprite_Health(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/HUD/hud_heartFull.png")
        self.rect = self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (35,10))

    def healthDeleted(self):
        ''' Upon collision with an enemy object
            this function will be called
            It's purpose is to remove health
         '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object, you must remove it from all [`pygame.sprite.Group`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). A *Sprite* can be removed from all *Groups* with [`kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html):

```py
class Player_sprite_Health(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def healthDeleted(self):
        self.kill()
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but it got the job done.

Comment: @FUTURE What did you want? Don't try to bypass the system. Use `kill` or `remove`.